# Confusion as to in which site to post question?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

I think the first time users feel a bit confused as to in which stack website should they post a question? I personally feel that while a person attempts to post a question (s)he should be made aware of the other stack websites which might be relevant to the question

Comment: What specific question did you ask that initially prompted this concern? You can always ask where to ask specific questions here or on site metas.

Comment: For example, I am an entrepreneur and have a question regarding a check deposit. The check did not had an expiration date mentioned and I want to know for how many days is a Banker's check valid in USA. Should I have asked it at starupBeta or Finance & Money?

Comment: @chanda Finance & Money. Your question is about bankers' checks (as you say, it is *regarding a check deposit*). Whatever purpose you are using it for, or whatever your occupation is, is irrelevant and isn't the topic. Remove "I am an entrepreneur" from your first sentence and it's still the same question. Being able to formulate your question precisely often helps you choose a site (and also often helps you understand your problem better). That said, although not the case in your example, some sites *do* overlap and that's OK.

Answer (score 10):

How would you achieve this other than by the current method of people reading the question and either voting to migrate to one of the current migration targets, flagging for a moderator to migrate or having a conversation with the OP in comments?

There are links to other sites in the footer of every page and some sites' help pages reference other sites that cover related topics.

I think these are sufficient.

Comment: thats right! But it can be improved by artificial intelligence. The system can judge the relevance of a question to a particular site at the point-of-entry itself by analysing the keywords. The challenge is to execute machine-learning and bring suggestions to users quickly.

Comment: @chandra nope, the member can simply read the links mentioned by ChrisF etc.

Answer (score 4):

There are three good ways to find out where your question belongs.

The first and foremost way is to put research effort into your own question. In doing so, you may find that your problem becomes more well-defined, and the place to ask it becomes clearer:

- An internet search for your question may yield a solution. As a bonus, that solution may be on an SE site (which Google, at least, places a lot of weight on), thus giving you an idea of where to ask similar questions in the future.
- An internet search for some of your problem keywords plus "stack exchange" generally yields reasonable results, without requiring you to know what sites are actually available before hand.
- A site listing is always available at https://stackexchange.com/sites (by clicking "All Sites" at the top of the main SE site).

The second way is the current system, [as mentioned in ChrisF's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251182/230261), which is primarily driven by human intelligence rather than machine intelligence (re: your comment on said answer):

- Readers who know where it belongs can vote or flag to migrate.
- Often a reader will leave a comment with a suggested site.

This system works well.

The third way, which can often be used in conjunction with the above, is to ask where to ask your specific question on the meta of a related site, or even here on MSE, or in one of the chat rooms (click "chat" in footer or see chat links on right). You will almost certainly receive good suggestions.

Comment: thanks for the explanation!